# ios custom font in [UINavigationController appearance] titletextapperance crashes app

Tags: ios

I have an application that is using a custom font. I am having issue setting the font of the nav bar with the Appearance property.

I have added the fonts to my project, and added them the my info.plist file as well.

Here is my ode to set the font:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                                        NSFontAttributeName: [Refrigerator boldFontWithSize:24.0f]}];
```

Here is my custom Refridgerator object for managing fonts:

```
+ (UIFont *)boldFontWithSize:(NSInteger)size {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"RefrigeratorDeluxe-Bold" size:size];
}
```

And here is a screenshot of where I got the "proper" font name from Font Book:

[image]

The error I get is this:

```
[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]
```

If I change this to something simple like "systemFont" then the error does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the font files to your Info.plist with the `UIAppFonts` key.

You could also check the spelling of the font name using;

```
for (NSString *familyName in [UIFont familyNames]) {
    for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:familyName]) {
        NSLog(@"family: '%@' font: '%@'", familyName, fontName);
    }
}
```

or

```
for (NSString *fontName in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"RefrigeratorDeluxe"]) {
    NSLog(@"font: '%@'", fontName);
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I have already added the font files themselves to the info.plist file. I have edited to post to better reflect this.

Comment: Did you see my edit? Can you check the font name as mentioned?

Comment: As Julian mentioned.. Log out the font names to make sure you have got it right.. If you can't see the font logged out then it hasn't been added correctly. You want to append the font name onto the family name with a space to create the custom font.

Comment: Looks like the font is not showing up in the list of fonts, so I must be adding it incorrectly? I have checked that each font has been added to "Copy Bundle Resources" and that it has been added to the plist file. Additionally, I have one other custom font that is setup identical and is working/showing up. May this have something to do with it?